# How to apply a sheet's theme to a range of excel cells using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm writing a software that creates Synoptic representations using Excel. So I deal with the Interop class. I'm now done with it, but i want to translate the Macros in order to gain time.

I would like to know if it is possible to apply a 'theme' worksheet to a range of cells, instead of changing every parameter one by one in a loop.

The theme worksheet would be in the same workbook as the synoptic tree. You can see belox the pictured explaination.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvjvM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nydQM.png)

Thank you very much for your help!

[EDIT]

I have found a way to do what I want, which should work. I created the 'table' in other worksheets of the same workbook. Before filling it with my data, I think copying the range of cells from the 'theme' worksheet to the worksheet I want it to be could work.

Here is what i've written so far :

```
Excel.Worksheet xlVBA_3 = _xlWB.Sheets[12];          // WS I want my data on
Excel.Worksheet xlBpeChambre = _xlWB.Sheets[6];      // WS where the table is with the merged cells and the borders edited
Excel.Range from = xlBpeChambre.Range["C3","AP33"];
Excel.Range to = xlVBA_3.Range[xlVBA_3.Cells[_iRowCursor - 13, _iColumnCursor], xlVBA_3.Cells[_iRowCursor + 17, _iColumnCursor + 39]];
from.Copy(to);
```

But, for a reason I don't understand, the table is not copied. Is there an issue we can see with the syntax ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show [mcve] for "applying a 'theme' worsheet to a range of cells, changing every parameter one by one in a loop."?

Comment: Hi thanks! So  imagine every node has data in it, and the node's format is applied by the Macro, cell by cell. I'd like to simply fill the data in the range and then apply the node's theme which is contained in another worksheet.

Comment: Let me know if that's not clear enough!

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question correspondingly.

Comment: I'm sorry the way I put it was a bit confusing! I've embedded 2 pictures showing for the first one the grid of the data i want to input. On the second one, the 'theme' I'd like to applydirectly.